# not able to redirect users to another page with hyper link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I have requirement where users are redirected youtube.com by using hyperlink control using below

I want to change the URL dynamically based on drop down list selected item by using below code.

```
protected void ddlPType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = ddlPType.SelectedIndex;

    if (x == 0)
    {
        activateCerts.NavigateUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";
        activateCerts.Text = "activateCerts";
        activateCerts.Target = "_blank";
        //activateCerts.HRef = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";

    }
    else if (x == 1)
    {
        //activateCerts.Target = "_blank";
        //activateCerts.HRef = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk3hxUuwg0w";
        activateCerts.Text = "activateCerts";
        activateCerts.NavigateUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";

    }
```

and this is the one aspx code

```
<asp:Label runat="server" style="padding-left:23rem;" Text="pls watch this video on How to"></asp:Label>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="activateCerts"  runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

but when I click on link I am not able to open a youtube video

Comment: Check `AutoPostBack=true` for dropdpwn `ddlPType`

Comment: checked auto postback is true and  I solved the problem by putting this check on pageLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me by setting `AutoPostBack=true` for dropdpwn `ddlPType` :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPType" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPType_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1"  Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
<br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="padding-left:23rem;" Text="pls watch this video on How to"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="activateCerts"  runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
</form>
```

.cs Page :

```
   protected void ddlPType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = ddlPType.SelectedIndex;

        if (x == 0)
        {
            activateCerts.NavigateUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";
            activateCerts.Text = "activateCerts";
            activateCerts.Target = "_blank";
            //activateCerts.HRef = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";

        }
        else if (x == 1)
        {
            //activateCerts.Target = "_blank";
            //activateCerts.HRef = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk3hxUuwg0w";
            activateCerts.Text = "activateCerts";
            activateCerts.NavigateUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Dropdownlist named ddlPType, you need to make sure its AutoPostBack is true. You can set it in the Attribute Panel, or using the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPType" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPType_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

By this step you should achieve your goal, but sometimes this is not that simple. You may need to make sure you put your data-bind (if there is) in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

in Page_Load.

Also, Dropdownlist will only send data when the data is changed. That is to say, if you get two options sharing the same value, Dropdownlist may not respond you. For example:

```
if(!IsPostBack) 
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(),"same_value")); 
}
```

Here comes the most strange situation: you have done all above but it still does not work. Sometimes it happens in IE8. If you use window.showModalDialog() to show DropDownList, submitting will leads you to a new page. You need to add between head tag:

```
<base target=_self></base>
```

Hope my experience will do help.